# Can your succah schach also be your walls?

Tags: sukkah, schach

Does the schach need to be completely detached from the walls of the succah?

Let's say that you build a "pipe" succah. You get a giant bamboo mat, and spread it out so that it not only covers the roof of the succah, but it also covers all 4 walls (minus an entranceway) on the sides of the succah.

Is this OK?

Comment: Why do you suppose this wouldn't be ok?

Comment: @Daniel See the opening question. Along with that, how would you know it's "schach" if everything is 1 continuous piece. Or does that not matter?